# Connected to China VPN but Not Sending All Traffic Over Connection; US IP, No Facebook

Tags: macos, networking, vpn

I use Astrill VPN's China server to access certain sites that are blocked outside China (yes, strange use case I know). I have been trying to split traffic so I don't lose access to sites like Facebook.

After a lot of trial and error, I noticed this strange scenario

- "Send all traffic over VPN connection" unchecked
- external IP is in US
- Facebook / Twitter still inaccessible

Why is this? Can someone educate me?

Answer (score 0):

In China, the internet is controlled by its government. You can't go to the website freely as you want. If you still can't browse with VPN, then it's about your VPN setting. Or check the compatibility with your browser. See if you have set in your browser properly.

Different VPNs have different authorities. As I know, you can try the free GoAgent in Goole Chrome. It really works well.